# How to prioritize filter in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a query optimization where I need to prioritize my filters, i.e. ordering of applying those filters. For example, if I have one property `prop1` and one relation `rel1` and I need to apply filter on `prop1` first and then `rel2`, then how should I proceed?

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)
where e.prop1 > constant1
and (e)-[:rel1]->(:Entity2)
return e.entity_id
```

I need this because if I apply `prop1` filter first, then search space will reduce drastically which should optimize performance. Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints are applied in the order you have specified. In your case `e.prop1 > constant1` is executed first.

Since you are using and `AND` operator, when the first test (the test in the left side of AND) fails, the second test are not executed. Remember that when using `AND` both conditions (left and right) should be `true`. Otherwise the AND expression will be `false`. This way the execution of the second constraint is not necessary when the first fail.

Comment: Also, if you have an index on :Entity(prop1), the planner will take advantage of that and automatically use your predicate on prop1 to perform a NodeIndexSeekByRange, and only after those starting nodes are found will the pattern match filter be evaluated.